# Add onclick to list view in navigation menu

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

[image]

I added a `RecyclerView` to the navigation view. And then Added listArray to the `RecyclerView`. But I can't implement `onclick` Listener for that `RecyclerView` items. Implementing `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` is correct?
please tell me how to implement `onclicklistener`.
this is my code.

in `MainActivity` I am adding stringlist-array like this

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
  val recyclerview = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.menuitems)
    recyclerview.layoutManager =
        LinearLayoutManager(this.applicationContext, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
   val names = Arrays.asList(*resources.getStringArray(R.array.dashboard_menu))
    val adapter = sidemenuAdapter(names)
    recyclerview.adapter = adapter
```

layout file

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/sidenavi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/sidenavi_headerlayout"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.022"
        >



        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/menuitems"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />
</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

in onNavigationclicklistener i tried like this but it is not working

```
 override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
      when(item.order){
          2-> startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, TimetableActivity::class.java)) 

      }
        return true
    }
```

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="dashboard_menu">
        <item>Home</item>
        <item>Class Time Table</item>
        <item>Leave Request</item>
        <item>Attendance Information</item>
        <item>Exam result</item>
        <item>Visual Tour</item>
        <item>About </item>
        <item>Careers</item>
        <item>Events</item>
        <item>Previews</item>
        <item>General Enquiry</item>
        <item>Live Chat</item>
        <item>FAQ\'s</item>
        <item> Club / Membership</item>
        <item>Contact Us</item>
        <item>Logout</item>
    </string-array>
```

can anyone tell me how to implememnt on click to this array items

Comment: why do you have a recyclerview in your navigationview ?

Comment: because the menu items list is too big and i have buttons of social media at the bottom of the navigation drawer. if i dont use the recycler view the social media button are overlapping on last 2 menu items

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to use `NavigationView` and the `menu.xml` that is associated with, you don't need to use a `RecyclerView` inside a `NavigationView`

Here is a short tutorial that might help you set this up, it also include the `onClick`: https://www.journaldev.com/12648/navigationview-android

EDIT: If you are committed to use `RecyclerView` you should go in your Adapter and set the `onClickListener`.

```java
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String mItem;
    private TextView mTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTextView = (TextView) view;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        mItem = item;
        mTextView.setText(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick " + getPosition() + " " + mItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: IF i dont use recycler view social media icons are displaying on top of last 2 menu items.By using recyclerview i kept margin bottom and view is perfect without overlap am adding my screen please check it